# MongoDB POJO custom Codecs for nested Classes

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo

mongodb-driver-sync version 3.8.2

I'm trying to write a Class `Parent` into the MongoDB database.

```
class Parent {

  private Child child;

}

class Child {

  private int a;
  private String b;

}
```

I want to have custom codecs for both Classes and register them in a central location:

```
 ConnectionString connString = new ConnectionString(connectionString);

 MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyConnectionString(connString)
        .codecRegistry(
            CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(
                        ////////////////////
                        //// HERE///////////
                        ////////////////////
                     new ParentCodec(), new ChildCodec()
                ))
        ).build();

MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings);
........
```

However I'm unable to find out how to implement `ParentCodec` correctly. Any examples I find are newing a DocumentCodec inside their custom Codec, which they then use to encode the document they generate, like so:

```
public class ParentCodec implements Codec<Parent> {

  private Codec<Document> documentCodec = new DocumentCodec();

  @Override
  public void encode(BsonWriter bsonWriter,
                     Parent parent,
                     EncoderContext encoderContext)
  {
    Document doc = new Document();

    doc.put("child", parent.getChild());

    documentCodec.encode(bsonWriter, doc, encoderContext);
  }
}
```

This fails, because the newed DocumentCodec only knows the codecs in the DefaultCodecRegistry:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class package.Child.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:184)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeIterable(DocumentCodec.java:207)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:180)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:199)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:141)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
```

Is there any way around this? I mean, I could obviously do something like this:

```
public class ParentCodec implements Codec<Parent> {

  private Codec<Document> documentCodec = new DocumentCodec(
      CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
          MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
          CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(
              new ChildCodec()
          )));
```

But this is ugly and I lose out on being able to register all my codecs in one central location. Anything else, that I missed?

Comment: You just new your ChildCodec and use it in ParentCodec. That's how it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the CodecRegistry to your codecs. Then in the codecs, get the DocumentCodec from the registry (using `registry.get(Document.class)`) instead of calling `new`.

The DocumentCodec will then be aware of all of the other Codecs in the registry.

##### ParentCodec

```
public class ParentCodec implements Codec<Parent> {
    private final CodecRegistry registry;
    private final Codec<Document> documentCodec;

    /**
     * Registry constructor.
     *
     * @param registry The CodecRegistry to use.
     */
    public ParentCodec(CodecRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
        this.documentCodec = this.registry.get(Document.class);
    }
    // ...
}
```

##### Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
        codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new ParentCodec(codecRegistry), new ChildCodec(codecRegistry)),
            codecRegistry
        );
        // ...
    }
}
```